# Get videos and images from Yammer API with bearer

Tags: yammer

We can get posts with its images and videos, but when we try access to this URLs authentication is required.

Anyone knows how to access to image and photos URLs without authentication throught Yammer API??

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour to better understand SO community http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved.

In attachments json properties appear api call to get attachments.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I am having trouble showing the images for different users

Comment: this is a next to useless answer.